# Identify background color of an element in webpage

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, automation

I have a requirement in my testing automation, i need to identify the background color of a web element.

I am able to find out if the test is highlighted but unable to find the background color of the same. Please help me find a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you doing at the moment? Show us the code you are using now. If you are able to find out it's 'highlighted' already, the code probably isn't much different.

Comment: I have a webpage which has many saw 20 URI's along with small description for the URI. We have a feature called internal search, where in using that search only particular text will be highlighted. I wanted to test this scenario, but doing internal search and verifying background color of a text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getComputedStyle` to test this kind of thing (MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle), it returns a style object (much like `element.style`) with the computed values. Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eBPEd/ I believe some engines have slightly different implementations so you might need to work around that as well.

If you're already using jQuery the `.css` method should return computed values as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting the CSS property value?

```
driver.find_element_by_id("id").value_of_css_property("color")
```

That will return you the rgb hex values as a string, `rgb(0,0,0)`, as long as you know what you expect you can easily assert whether it is correct.

Apologies for expressing that in `python`, my `java` is a little rusty.